# Emacs Org-Mode: how to fold block without going to block header?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I know I can go to a block header and fold/unfold by hitting the TAB key.
However suppose I'm inside a block that has hundreds of lines, and I just want to fold the *current* block, *without* having to go to the block header -- is there a keyboard short-cut that can do that? Or is there an elisp function that does that, so that I can bind some shortcut to that function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a keybinding that performs the following function:

```lisp
(defun zin/org-cycle-current-headline ()
  (interactive)
  (outline-previous-heading)
  (org-cycle))
```

This will jump back to the previous headline and then cycle.  Since the headline is already open, it will close it.  It also places the point at the start of the headline.

If you wrap the two commands in `(save-excursion )` it will retain the point, however that could lead to entering information inside the ellipsis without realizing it.  Alternately you can change the command to call a non-interactive form:

```lisp
(defun zin/org-cycle-current-headline ()
  (interactive)
  (org-cycle-internal-local))
```

This is equivalent to the above with `(save-excursion )`.

Comment: Thank you, I mapped "C-c t" to the first function above, and it works very well.

Answer (score 4):

`C-c C-p` will get you to the heading, `TAB` will fold. You can create a keyboard macro for this, or the equivalent ELISP:

```
(defun up-n-fold ()
  (interactive)
   (progn
     (outline-previous-visible-heading 1)
     (org-cycle)))
```

Edit: corrected C-c p for C-c C-p as noted by many below. Thanks!

Comment: `C-c p` (or any `C-c <char>`) should not be bound to anything by default. That is reserved for end-user configuration, and (in Emacs 24 at least) org-mode appears to respect this convention. Perhaps you should check what you have that bound to?

Comment: C-c C-p *and* C-c C-n are now and always have been, AFAIK, bound to outline-previous-visible-heading and outline-next-visible-heading.
I think this was a typo by Juancho.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether such a function exists, but it is not hard to create one. Just replace the following keystrokes with functions: <kbd>C-M-r</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: That won't work as such.  C-M-r does `isearch-backwards` not a regexp search, so ^ is not start of line.  Secondly, you need to be on the headline to cycle.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin: In my emacs, C-M-r runs `isearch-backward-regexp`. `isearch-backwards` is run by C-r.